How to use continue training coquiTTS model in google colab?
I'm training a model in coqui TTS using Google Colab, I saw that there is a way to continue training from a checkpoint, but all examples show how to use --continue_path with the code into a train.py file, but I am training my model with functions separated by cells instead of using a file, so the common method doesn't work for me.

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive') 
!python train.py --continue_path '/content/drive/MyDrive/Models/***'

